# MySQL WhereIn Query with Multidimentional Array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array, where-in

I have the following multidimentional array, and I'm trying to figure out how to access the second layer with a `whereIn` query in MySql:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "allbeauty.com UK" [1]=> int(37617) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "Feelunique UK" [1]=> int(54161) } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "Fragrancedirect" [1]=> int(9) } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "Mankind UK" [1]=> int(987) } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "Perfume Click" [1]=> int(12281) } }
```

The array is called `$bar['merchants']['awin']` and therefore I thought a simple MySQL query like so would suffice:

```
$model->whereIn('merchant', $bar['merchants']['awin'])->groupBy('merchant')->findAll();
```

I'm trying to find a way of accessing only the `[0]` element within each of the second-level arrays ie. "allbeauty.com UK", "Feelunique UK", "Fragrancedirect"... etc.

Is there something along the lines of this... `$bar['merchants']['awin'][$i][0]` ... that I can use within a MySQL statement?

Comment: The concept of multidimensional arrays doesn't apply in SQL. Moreover, while SQL is likely being used at a lower layer, the code sample indicates an intermediary database abstraction layer or data access layer is being used. This question would be clearer if stated in RDB terms (e.g. column, row, table, join), the data layer were explicitly mentioned, and a solution either at the DAL or DB level were asked for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [codeigniter flatten array of query result](//stackoverflow.com/q/12545973/)